# How to sort my list of most frequent 3-mers in ascending order?

Tags: c++, c, bioinformatics

I am writing a code to find out most frequent 3-mers in a DNA sequence. I wrote a code that counts the occurrence of a 3-mer and if it greater than 1 then code records both string and number of occurrences.

This is giving me a list that is redundant in nature. I want to sort the list such that I only see each 3-mer once in the list.

Below is the code that wrote:

```
int main()
{
    char dna[1000];
    char read[3] = {0};
    char most_freq[3];

    printf("Enter the DNA sequence\n");
    fgets(dna, sizeof(dna), stdin);
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<strlen(dna)-3; i++)
    {

        read[0] = dna[i];
        read[1] = dna[i+1];
        read[2] = dna[i+2];
        int count=0, maxcount=1;
        for(j = 0; j < strlen(dna); j++)
        {
            if(dna[j] == read[0] && dna[j+1] == read[1] && dna[j+2] == read[2])
            {
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        if(count > maxcount)
        {
            maxcount = count;
            
           printf("%s %d\n", read, maxcount);
        }

    }
}
```

This is what I get if I input :

> CGCCTAAATAGCCTCGCGGAGCCTTATGTCATACTCGTCCT

```
CGC 2
GCC 3
CCT 4
ATA 2
AGC 2
GCC 3
CCT 4
CTC 2
TCG 2
CGC 2
AGC 2
GCC 3
CCT 4
GTC 2
ATA 2
CTC 2
TCG 2
GTC 2
CCT 4
```

It is clear that the answer is CCT but I don't want redundancy in output. How do I resolve this?

Comment: You could use a *set* (more precisely a *multi-set*) to store the result. Or some kind of *map* which maps the 3-mers to a count. Or just a dynamic array of structures containing the 3-mer and the count, which you then can sort, remove duplicates from, and display.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The problem was tagged as `C` not `C++`

Comment: @AlexShirley I haven't mentioned any specific implementations (except the dynamic array of structures), only general data-structures that are available or can be implemented in any language.

Comment: Maybe Jellyfish (fast k-mer counting)  [link](https://www.cbcb.umd.edu/software/jellyfish/)

Comment: I am trying to write my own code for the problem. But, jellyfish is an option if things don't work the way I want them to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a reasonably fast way to do it in `C`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    char n_base[4];
    int count;
} NMer_3;

typedef struct {
    int count;
    NMer_3 trimer[4 * 4 * 4];
} dict;

int cmp(const void* a, const void* b) {
    return strncmp((char*)a, (char*)b, 3);
}

void insertTrimer(dict* d, char c[3]) {
    NMer_3* ptr = (NMer_3*)bsearch((void*)c, (void*)d->trimer, d->count,
                                   sizeof(NMer_3), cmp);
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        int offset = d->count;
        strncpy(d->trimer[offset].n_base, c, 3);
        d->trimer[offset].count = 1;
        d->count++;
        qsort(d->trimer, d->count, sizeof(NMer_3), cmp);
    } else {
        ptr->count++;
    }
}

int main() {
    char dna[1000];
    dict d;
    printf("Enter the DNA sequence\n");
    char* res = fgets(dna, sizeof(dna), stdin);
    if (res == NULL)
        return 1;
    char* ptr = &dna[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(dna) - 2; i++)
        insertTrimer(&d, ptr++);
    for (int i = 0; i < d.count; i++)
        printf("%s : %d\n", d.trimer[i].n_base, d.trimer[i].count);
    return 0;
}
```

Basically, each 3-mer is an entry in a larger struct. The larger struct is binary-searched, and q-sorted every time a new 3-mer is found. Otherwise, if a repeat is found, their entry is incremented.

Here is the result used with your input

```
AAA : 1
AAT : 1
ACT : 1
AGC : 2
ATA : 2
ATG : 1
CAT : 1
CCT : 4
CGC : 2
CGG : 1
CGT : 1
CTA : 1
CTC : 2
CTT : 1
GAG : 1
GCC : 3
GCG : 1
GGA : 1
GTC : 2
TAA : 1
TAC : 1
TAG : 1
TAT : 1
TCA : 1
TCC : 1
TCG : 2
TGT : 1
TTA : 1
```

Ways to improve the speed:

- Use a program like Jellyfish
- Use a hashmap. There's no standard C-library for hashmaps/tables. You're basically going to do something very similar to what I did here. Memory management might be a challenge. However, you're going to be doing a O(1) search for each 3-mer in the sequence, instead of O(log(n)), additionally, adding will only be O(1) instead of needing O(n*log(n)) sorting.

If you do it in C++, you get a lot of benefits, the first being **much** simpler code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main() {
    std::string dna;
    printf("Enter the DNA sequence\n");
    std::getline(std::cin, dna);
    auto d = std::map<std::string,int>{};
    for (int i = 0; i < dna.size() - 2; i++){
        auto mer3 = dna.substr(i,3);
        auto itr = d.find(mer3);
        if (itr == d.end()){
            d[mer3] = 1;
        } else {
            itr->second += 1;
        }
    }
    for (auto i : d) std::cout << i.first << ':' << i.second << '\n';
    std::cout <<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is effectively the same as the C example.

If you replace `map` with `unordered_map` it becomes much faster, however, the output will not be sorted.