# C++ program to count redundant words in a string using recursion and structures

Tags: c++

I am writing a c++ program to display the count of characters, words and redundant(duplicate) words in a string(taken by the user) using recursion and structures.it will terminate when '#' is found in the string. I have done the part for characters and words but couldn't do the redundant count part. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `std::unordered_map`, storing the words as keys, and storing the count of each word, as the value.

Once you're walked the length of the input sentence, storing/incrementing the values of present words, then you can iterate from beginning to end of the hash-table, summing up all the values greater than count of 1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this is an assignment and i am a 2nd year student so the teacher wont allow the use of unordered_map. It will be helpful if u can share a more basic logic.

Comment: @FaizanShabbir, can you use bsearch and qsort? They're part of the stdlib and a nearly identical usage can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64458130/how-to-sort-my-list-of-most-frequent-3-mers-in-ascending-order/64528133#64528133

Comment: Also, you should put your other limitations in your original post.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the post. It's the first time i have posted a question on stack overflow.

Comment: And no i cannot use those lib's.

Comment: You could make your own binary search and sorting algorithm as private helper functions. They're pretty straight forward